# draw picture with absolute coordinate in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

Sometimes I want to draw some picture with absolute coordinate in `beamer`. but below example seems has some offset when draw a circle. How can I draw a picture at a absolute coordinate?

Current code:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[color=orange!10] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
    \draw[step=1.0,black,thin] (0,0) grid (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[t]{Title here}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[very thick]
    \def\r{2}
    \def\x0{5}
    \def\y0{5}
    \draw[fill=black] (\x0,\y0) circle (5pt);
    \draw (\x0,\y0) circle (\r);
    \draw [->] (\x0,\y0) -- (\x0+\r,\y0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I wish to draw a circle at (5,5) but current Output is:

[image]

Comment: The coordinate system used inside a `tikz` picture is not the same as used for the page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Then you need to switch to `overlay,remember picture` mode and shift your picture relative to the page. Then compile enough times

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[color=orange!10] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
    \draw[step=1.0,black,thin] (0,0) grid (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[t]{Title here}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[very thick,overlay,remember picture]
    \def\r{2cm}\def\x0{5cm}\def\y0{5cm}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(current page.south west)}]
    \draw[fill=black] (\x0,\y0) circle (5pt);
    \draw (\x0,\y0) circle (\r);
    \draw [->] (\x0,\y0) -- (\x0+\r,\y0);
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: "Then compile enough times..." that saved me, thanks!